# Xcode 13.3 Compiler Bug with multiple nil coalescing operators?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-bug

A friend came up with an issue with the nil coalescing operator starting with Xcode 13.3 and 13.3.1 (Swift 5.6), which I was able to reproduce.

The following example always crashes, but worked fine till Xcode 13.2.1.

```swift
fileprivate typealias Closure = () -> Void

func crash1() {
    let closure1: Closure? = nil
    let closure2: Closure? = nil
    let closure3: Closure? = nil
    print("Closures: \(String(describing: closure1)), \(String(describing: closure2)), \(String(describing: closure3))")
   
    let closure = closure1 ?? closure2 ?? closure3

    print("\(#line): \(String(describing: closure))")
    closure?() // <- EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    assert(closure == nil)
}

func crash2() {
    let closure1: Closure? = nil
    let closure2: Closure? = nil
    let closure3: Closure? = { }
    print("Closures: \(String(describing: closure1)), \(String(describing: closure2)), \(String(describing: closure3))")

    let closure = closure1 ?? closure2 ?? closure3

    print("\(#line): \(String(describing: closure))")
    closure?() // <- EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    assert(closure != nil)
}
```

We reported it via https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/58323 and as FB10005210.

My example:
[image]

The following works fine and does not crash:

```swift
let closure = (closure1 ?? closure2) ?? closure3
```

Is anybody aware of this? As a workaround we need to limit nil coalescing to two items or use parentheses.

Update for Xcode 14.0 beta (14A5228q):
Not crashing anymore, but closure is always nil, even if third coalescing returns a non-nil closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received feedback on FB10005210 from Apple today, resolved with Xcode 14 Beta 3, Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)